# The controller does not have time to process requests and ValidationPipe skips them

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs, class-validator

I have a form to add new items. When I click many times on the add button, it sends many requests. ValidationPipe checks for the first time whether the name is unique, and skips subsequent requests, because the controller has not had time to handle the first one yet.(added delay for 2 secs). As a result it creates dublicated items.

```
@Post()
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({
    forbidUnknownValues: true,
    exceptionFactory
  }))
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  async create(@Body() createItemDto: CreateItemDto, @Req() req: Request) {
    const token = req.cookies['at'];

    const { id } = await this.authService.verifyJwtToken(token);
    
    const item = Object.assign(createItemDto, {
      userId: id
    })

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));

    return await this.itemsService.create(item);
  }
```

Comment: Hi ptimer!
What exactly is the question? and what is the reason for a timeout of 2 seconds in the middle of your code? 
this will cause you script (and potentially server to start choking up / run out of memory (depending on how you have initiated the controller

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly you can Post many times before the first request is processed? You should create a queue which handles the create requests one at a time for the create endpoint (ideally per userId). Here you can read more about queues: (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues)